# Why do string input requests always get skipped?

Tags: c

I know others have asked similar questions but they are often old posts with outdated code and solutions.

Regardless of whether I use scanf_s or fgets, it always seems to get skipped despite the fact that I have done this the exact same way on other PCs with the same version of VS and they work fine.

```
int main() {
    char name[20];
    name[0] = 0;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf_s("%[^\n]%*c", &name[0], 20);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Your name is %s", name);
}
```

What am I doing wrong that makes this an issue now but not when this is done elsewhere?

EDIT: 
After recreating it and only it in another file and seeing a post (and commenting off certain sections and testing it) I now realize that another part of the code is messing with it. Specifically the `scanf_s("%d", &age);` of the following code:

```
int main() {
    int age;
    int ageDifference;
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &age);

    if (age == 18) {
        printf("You are 18 years old.");
    }
    else if (age > 18) {
        ageDifference = age - 18;
        printf("It has been %d years since you were 18.", ageDifference);
    }
    else {
        ageDifference = 18 - age;
        printf("It will be %d years before you are 18.", ageDifference);
    }
    printf("\n");


    char name[20];
    name[0] = 0;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf_s("%[^\n]%*c", name, 20);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Your name is %s", name);

    return 0;

}
```

Screenshot of output: https://prnt.sc/qdo38t

Why is it causing it to skip it though?

Sorry for being such a noob at C too.

FIXED: Adding a space so that `scanf_s("%[^\n]%*c", name, 20)` is now `scanf_s(" %[^\n]", name, 20)` fixed it. Also `%*c` is not needed. Thanks @Weather Vane.

Comment: You don't need to do `&name[0]` since name is already a pointer to the first character. You can just do `name`. But this works fine for me `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);`

Comment: "always seems to get skipped" makes sense it this is not your true code, but only a small pieces of it as prior I/O activity is leaving a `'\n'` in `stdin` for this code to pick up or block.  Post a [mcve] including example input and output seen.

Comment: With any input problems with `scanf(_s)()` family, report the return value.  Saves us all time.

Comment: With `fgets` too? Typically it's because there is already a newline character which was left in the input buffer. With `scanX` functions, instead of trying to clear trailing whitespace it is usually better to ensure you filter *leading* whitespace. In this case it can be done by adding a space before the format specifier `"%[^\n]`" as `" %[^\n]"`.

Comment: Re the edit: `scanf_s("%d", &age);` leaves a newline character in the buffer. Then `scanf_s("%[^\n]%*c", name, 20);` stops scanning at that newline.

Comment: @Nina Changed it, thanks for the info.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah that seems to make more sense now as I had that beforehand which I now included, unsure of what you mean by the second part though but I have posted a screenshot of the output.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, yeah merely adding a space before the ```%[^\n]%*c``` fixed it.

Comment: Please stop trying to remove the trailing newline with `scanf` functions. Focus on leading whitespace. Most format specifiers automatically filter leading whitespace except `%c` and `%[]`. Adding that space instructs the function to filter them. Also, don't mix input methods, such as `fgets` and `scanf`. Stick to one.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not sure what you mean by "trailing newline" but I see what you mean with the whitespace part. And no I wasn't going to mix them up, I was just testing to see if ```fgets``` would also work.

Comment: `%*c` is attempting to remove a trailing newline. But as you see, there was already one there. As I wrote, please stop doing this. Keep it simple.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see now, thanks again.

Comment: Your edited solution is not advised, please use `scanf_s(" %[^\n]", name, 20)`

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and read *carefully* the documentation of [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and of [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Consider using Linux. It gives you [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us walk through

```
printf("Enter your age: ");
```

User input <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
scanf_s("%d", &age);
```

`scanf()` reads `"66"`, *leaving*  the `'\n'` in `stdin`.

```
....
printf("Enter your name: ");
```

`scanf_s()` attmepts to read the `'\n'`, which does not meet the criteria of `"%[^\n]"`, so `scanf_s()` stops right away and does not return a 1 - still *leaving*  the `'\n'` in `stdin`.

```
scanf_s("%[^\n]%*c", name, 20)
```

Code did not check `scanf_s()` results, Tsk, tsk, and so does not know that `name[]` remains unchanged.

---

Using a space as in `" %[^\n]%*c"` helps, to first consume the left-over `'\n'`, but the best advice is to not use `scanf(), scanf_s()` at all. Use `fgets()` to read a *line* into a *string* and then parse the string with `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc.

In all cases, check the return value of input functions.